# I bought an airgun in Patna, India - can I take it to other cities by train or on road?

Tags: legal, india

I have bought an air pistol .22 mm, 35 model in Bihar. Can I take it to other cities? Is there any law against transporting this? Does mode of transport matter?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about the firearm laws and not travel.

Comment: I'm up voting this question about because it's about travel.